# The API I am using returns a dataframe - how do I return multiple DFs using a list and then merge these?

Tags: python, pandas, stock

I am trying to write a simple function which takes in a list of stock names and then uses an API to create a pandas data frame out of it. I would then like to merge these data frames or be able to access them separately.

The api call takes a name and returns a pandas data frame. Here is my attempted code below:

```
stock_list = ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
frames = []

def get_stocks(stock):
    for stock in stock_list:
        stock, meta_data = ts.get_daily_adjusted(symbol=stock, outputsize='compact')
        frames.append([stock])

get_stocks(stock_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(frames)
```

The list variable I created 'Frames' contains a list of list based on all the of the different dataframes. When I try to make this into one DF however, the DF returns nothing. Any idea how to do this? Or a way to return data frames as separate variables from within the function?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the frames variable is a list of list that contains 4 data frames, each with 100 rows and 8 columns.

Comment: I think your issue is that you have a `list` **of lists** of DataFrames (not a list of DataFrames). If `stock` is a list of DataFrames returned from `ts.get_daily...` then you probably want `frames.extend(stock)` and `df=pd.concat(frames)` in the end

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Perhaps I am describe the problem incorrectly. To give some context, when I run `Frames[0]` I am returned with "<bound method DataFrame.reset Index of...>` and then data frame appears as 100 rows, 8 columns but in a list format.

Comment: That makes it seem like there's an issue in ` ts.get_daily_adjusted`, which isn't returning a DataFrame but a DataFrame method that was never called.

Comment: Thanks I see now! It returns a bound Dataframe method. Is there a way to transform this into an actual pandas data frame?